# How to show checkbox only when getView( ) is called

Tags: android, checkbox

Hello i'm developing simple todo list app..and I ran into this problem
I want to show checkbox Dynamically but since i created it in my xml with following attributes...it is automatically shown and 
`<CheckBox
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_width="353dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:checked="false" />`
when i played with it,i figured out that listView's first row is being shown [image: screen 1]

[image: screen2]
[image: screen3 notice a line below the button]

i tried to change the visibility of checkbox but i think it is the issue with list view..

```
static class ViewHolder{
    TextView textView;

    ViewHolder(View v){
        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row= convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;CheckBox checkBox;
    if(row == null){//1st time
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,parent,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
   else{//recycling
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    MainActivity.Task singleTask=  list.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(singleTask.getNote());

        checkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    //if(position >=0)
      //  checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    return row;
}
```

this is my arrayAdapter class...
please help me with this...thanks in advance!!

Comment: in xml don't put any child in the listview. make a xml layout with textbox and checkbox, inflated that view and pupulate the listview with this inflated view

Comment: or may be i didn't understand what u said!!
can you please explain a little bit!

Comment: yeah, i didn't read all code, I was telling you the concept

Comment: I really don't like the way your question is

Comment: you need to learn or start tutorial first before asking any question

Comment: @ArslanAhmad what kind of tutorial can u please give me the link...coz this way i would be blocked from asking any question!!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a custom listview, with custom listview items having checkbox and textbox....
You can see the tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) and [here.](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html)

Using custom listview would be the correct and right approach.

And good luck with your first android app ;)

Comment: if (holder.textView.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            return null; 
i tried something like this!!but still not working

Comment: why are you not using something like http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

Comment: you can't return null, you must return a View

Comment: thanks a lot..i didn't know about that...its my first app that I'm developing without watching tutorials!

Comment: I think you are new to android, if so, you must see the link i sent you... Use android checkbox listview, might be lengthy process but you will learn a lot and its the best and the right way to do it

Comment: @shunryuinik i have edited my answer, mark it correct if it helps, which i hope it will :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, modify the code to your needs, its important that you return the size of the list in getCount() and getItem returns current item.
I prefer to pass the list and the context to the adapter's constructor.

```
public class TasksListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Task> mTasksList;

    public TasksListAdapter(Context context, List<Task> tasksList) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mTaskList = tasksList;
    }
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        CheckBox check;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(this.mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            holder.check = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.text.setText(this.mTasksList.get(position).getNote());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.mTasksList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.mTasksList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is not layout's problem but the Apdater

**What the return value of function *getCount* ?**

You not provide detail code, so I guess, if first time init listview, is *getCount* return 1, and in *getView* param *convertView* is null, at this time list size should be 0, why when you call *singleTask.getNote()* haven't throw exception ?

Maybe you can just logcat in some place, it can find the problem

- list.size() = ?
- singleTask is null ?
- singleTask.getNote() return is null ?
- getCount() return = ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try a different approach, like creating in the xml both checkbox and text view, and then inflate it in the listview row.

Here is an example.

http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/2012/09/android-multiple-select-listview.html